# Move mails of specific sender into specific calendar in Outlook for Mac

Tags: outlook, outlook-calendar, outlook-mac

Is it possible on a Mac and, if so, how, to move the events which are received from a specific sender into a specific calendar?

Outlook rules seem to allow categorizing incoming events by tag, which will color them in the calendar. Is it also possible to move them into a different calendar?

Otherwise, would it be possible to do a workaround using the apple-calendar as an interface to outlook and controlling the event movement with an apple script?